# Significance of Pgr_trsp() Function returning -1 in id1 column

Tags: pgrouting

I want to understand what's the significance of -1 value in column id1 of pgr_trsp() function output. When I run the below query I was excepting the source and target edge to be snapped according to the floating value I provided as input, So that my final route is snapped precisely to my point of start and end. But pgr_trsp() gave the entire route without snapping. Instead it just had -1 value in column id1. This made me ask what the use of this -1 value. Is there another function we can use to snap the route based on this value. Below is query.

```
SELECT * FROM pgr_trsp('SELECT feat_id as id, source, target, cost_len as cost FROM test.table_route', 
5,
0.5,
600,
0.2,
false, false) AS shortestPath
JOIN test.table_route nav ON shortestPath.id2 = nav.id order by seq;
```

Here 5 and 600 are the id of my start and end edges. 0.5 and 0.2 are my floating values to snap the start and end edges.